# Calculating price impact on Uniswap V3

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I need to calculate the price impact on Uniswap V3 to further compute the bid-ask spreads. What would be the mathematical formula and which data do I need?

Thank you in advance for the help I'll keep the post updated with my research

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to have a single mathematical formula as a swap Uniswap v3 may cross tick range boundaries. Each tick range may have different liquidity and needs to be considered separately. The multi-step swapping algorithm is given in the [whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf), Figure 4.

For a single step, the [`computeSwapStep` logic](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/SwapMath.sol#L21) may be used. Alternatively, look at formulas 6.9 to 6.16 in the whitepaper and implement the logic yourself.

**Edit:** If access to on-chain data is an option, the best solution may be to call the [QuoterV2 contract](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/lens/QuoterV2) using a static call, as it returns not only the amount, but also the `sqrtPriceX96After`, which can be compared with the pool's previous `sqrtPriceX96` to directly get the price impact.